# What is check in and check out in SharePoint Designer 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I edited a wiki page without checking out and made some changes, but other users can not see my changes. Why does it need to be checked in?

Other user get this message:

> “The current page has been customized from its template. Revert to
>   template.”

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking out a document or page lets you work on the item while everyone else still sees the previously checked in version. Once you're done making your edits, you check it back in to allow others to see your changes. In some cases, you also have to Publish the page.

Users who see the option to "Revert to template" are users who have permissions to modify the page. So I, as an owner with full control, would see this message, while a user with only read access would not see this message because they aren't allowed to revert the page to template.

Comment: Hey i edit the my page without check out,  so how can i check in this changes ? Some user get this message but not my changes "Revert to template"  why?

Comment: Will you add a screenshot of the Document tab of your ribbon for that page?

Comment: Check please http://prnt.sc/cfmwp0

Comment: Everything looks right. I don't know why others can't see the changes.

Comment: I edit the my page without check out, so how can i check in this changes ?

Comment: Does it look like it's checked out in Designer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45121/discussion-between-erin-l-and-admin).

Answer (score 0):

Hi the above is due to the ghosting and unghosting (or if you prefer the new Term Customized/Un-Customized) of the site pages.For better understanding refer to [Link](http://www.codedigest.com/FAQ/11-What-is-the-concept-of-ghosting-and-unghosting-in-SharePoint-.aspx)